# Reverse POCO only new tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

I'm learning EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator to generate files from database.

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I generate POCO class using the tt file for ONLY the newly created tables? Assume I have 100 tables and created POCO class already, if I add 2 more tables to the database, and save the "tt" file. Will it create all 102 new classes or just the "2" new classes? If it recreates, then how do I avoid it?
2. Similarly, if I update any existing tables, and save it - Will it recreate ONLY those "modified" tables, or the entire database tables? If it recreates, then how do I avoid it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see for yourself?

Comment: @BrianOgden I tried doing that, I believe it recreates them. I wanted to know how to avoid that, because my DB has over 1000 tables and don't want them to recreate everytime if I make changes to generate POCO

Comment: I can tell you really do not understand that much about what you are asking or English is not your native language. If it is an issue of understanding, I can say one point about your question, I do not think you have an actual concern, why would you care if .cs class files are being recreated every time, they are just text files?

Comment: Can I filter in the "tt" file to recreate ONLY the files I wanted along with the existing files? Yes, just text files getting recreated, but I'm asking if that can be avoided by any chance?

Comment: BUT WHY do you care? Do you have a slow hard drive? Are you editing the generated.cs files because if you are stop right now, they are partials and you can extend their nature in another C# .cs partial of the same class name. Why do care about text files being recreated? You have to be do something wrong since you do care.

Comment: The POCO generator allows you to pick what you want. It is intended to get you to a "Code First" workflow where all subsequent changes are made in code and then you generate the database changes via migrations. The process you are using is "Database First" so you should use that workflow with EDMX. See [here](https://www.itsolutions-inc.com/news-and-training/article/entity-framework-6-database-first-versus-code-first/)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I just thought if there was an option to do what I asked, but looks like it won't